# App Center package website down

Tags: appcenter, apt, repositories

I upgraded the App Center to 0.2.3, but then the site,  http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter, the packages are hosted on is reporting a bad gateway. The App Center isn't showing anything other than the default apps that come with my fresh install of Elementary OS.

When running sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade I get the error:

Reading package lists... Done
...
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  521  Origin Down [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wait, the error will be fixed soon

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure the Elementary team and other users saw it.